# Swap content and partitions of two large drives without space to store both

Tags: backup, ssd, storage

I have a 512gb ssd which I use to store much of my backups and data, and also have a 1tb ssd which isn't being used much. I've been wanting to swap them, but I don't have another drive that is large enough to store an image of either drive. Is there a way to swap the contents on the drives without having to use a large intermediary storage?

The 512 gb drive:

```
/dev/sdb1 469G 290G 155G 66% /mnt/ssd

NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  79.9M  1 loop /snap/core/9069
loop1         7:1    0  79.9M  1 loop /snap/core/8936
sda           8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   256M  0 part 
└─sda2        8:2    0   119G  0 part /
sdb           8:16   0   477G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0   477G  0 part /mnt/ssd
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.8G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  29.5G  0 part 

/dev/sdb1: UUID="5c293db6-6b16-48db-af86-732e081b2a0e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3c32c42c-01"
```

The 1tb drive:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/root       938G   42G  850G   5% /
devtmpfs        328M     0  328M   0% /dev
tmpfs           458M     0  458M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            92M  1.3M   91M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           458M     0  458M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      142M  142M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1139
/dev/loop2      142M  142M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1146
/dev/loop1       49M   49M     0 100% /snap/core18/1753
/dev/loop3       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/lxd/14894
/dev/loop4       63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop5       49M   49M     0 100% /snap/core18/1708
/dev/loop6       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/lxd/14958
/dev/loop7       24M   24M     0 100% /snap/snapd/7267
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M  141M  112M  56% /boot/firmware
tmpfs            92M  4.0K   92M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs            92M  4.0K   92M   1% /run/user/1001
tmpfs            92M  8.0K   92M   1% /run/user/116

NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 141.6M  1 loop /snap/chromium/1139
loop1         7:1    0  48.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1753
loop2         7:2    0 141.6M  1 loop /snap/chromium/1146
loop3         7:3    0  61.4M  1 loop /snap/lxd/14894
loop4         7:4    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop5         7:5    0  48.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1708
loop6         7:6    0  61.5M  1 loop /snap/lxd/14958
loop7         7:7    0  23.5M  1 loop /snap/snapd/7267
sda           8:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 953.9G  0 part /
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.2G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  28.9G  0 part 

/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="system-boot" LABEL="system-boot" UUID="85F3-CC2B" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="da84cd12-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="writable" UUID="b96d647f-679e-4582-87d0-2d8c7afc91f4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="da84cd12-02"
/dev/sda1: UUID="bc8e0523-a221-4e72-a3a6-077762464ae4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8b3ac4b5-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of df that includes both disks? Are there multiple partitions, LVM, etc?

Comment: They are on different devices, this is the 512gb one
`/dev/sdb1       469G  290G  155G  66% /mnt/ssd`
The 1tb one is used as a root partition, I put it in my edited question since it's too long to put here

Comment: There is lots of free space. Therefore you could shrink one partition, create a new partition big enough to copy other to, copy the files, and then grow it. Use gparted live distro to do it. You must not be copying an active file-system.

Comment: Alright, so I can basically partition my 1tb drive to make another drive that can store and flash the images on

Comment: Would it make a difference when flashing that I'm writing to /dev/sdax now and not /dev/sda since the partition can't be deleted?

Comment: Can you pls. add the output of `lsblk` (while the 500GB drive is connected) as well as the output of `sudo blkid` to your question?